# Docker with mssql servers

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker, server

I have doubts on SQL server with docker.  If i have multiple MS SQL DB containers are running in my host, and it was accessed by the same Application with load balance. how the data base will replicate with in the containers ( Live).  can we use SQL Replication for this.  Kindly suggest on this.  i am new to this .

Regards,
Karthick V

Comment: The simple answer is Yes, of course. The hostname replica have to be the container name. And inside a docker network

Comment: When you say "multiple MS SQL DB containers are running in my host" do you mean multiple copies of the same DB within the same physical server? If yes, why would you do this?

Comment: not in a same physical server under same swarm cluster